# Usage Of Notwithstanding

Tags: sentence

I have to convert two sentences following a particular instruction.

1) We reminded him several times but he refused to pay.(Begin:Several... )(Use :"notwithstanding")

2)"In spite of the cold weather,many parents were present."(Begin:The cold weather...)(Use:notwithstanding )

I searched the net extensively.Got the best examples [here](http://www.grammarbank.com/notwithstanding.html)

Any ideas?Please help!!

Comment: You have to follow the instructions in your questions, but in British English "notwithstanding" is often at the *start* of the phrase it refers to, not the end. You can usually replace "notwithstanding" by "in spite of" without changing the meaning. or the word order.  http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/notwithstanding

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> 1) We reminded him several times but he refused to pay.(Begin:Several... )(Use :"notwithstanding")

Several reminders notwithstanding, he refused to pay.

> 2)"In spite of the cold weather,many parents were present."(Begin:The cold weather...)(Use:notwithstanding )

The cold weather notwithstanding, many parents were present.

Answer (score 1):

I voted to close this question because it was a homework question in which the poster showed no attempt to answer himself. Unfortunnately someone has done his homework for him, so I will give an answer explaining the unsatisfactory nature of the question.

> The instructions given for the use of *notwithstanding* are likely to
>   lead to clumsy sentences and should be ignored, where possible. If you
>   can, use *notwithstanding* at the start of a sentence — it is a far more
>   direct way of expression.

In support of this viewpoint I would cite the three of the four examples given for [notwithstanding in the Oxford Dictionary online](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/notwithstanding).

*Preposition*

> ‘**Notwithstanding** the evidence, the consensus is that the jury will not
>   reach a verdict’

*Adverb*

> ‘I didn't like it. **Notwithstanding**, I remained calm’

*Conjunction*

> ‘**Notwithstanding** that the hall was packed with bullies, our champion
>   played on steadily and patiently’

Comment: While this doesn't directly answer the question, a mod has previously advised me that a critique of the question itself does qualify as an answer. And since it's a well-presented and well-researched answer, +1 :-)